# Socket.io emitting events inside other server files

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

is it possible to emit events inside some other node.js server files?
Like I have the app.js running and also an other file running as well.

Inside the other server file I have

```
var io = require('socket.io');
```

And further in the files something like this (I want to send this data - price to the client).

```
io.emit('price', { price: price});
```

The error I get is io.emit is not a function. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have one `io` object that is hooked to your web server (to receive incoming socket.io connections) and then you need to share (via exporting or by calling a function and pass the `io` object) the one `io` object with any other file that wants to use it.

You don't show very much of your code, but imagine you initialize socket.io in your main express file:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// load msg module and give it the io variable
var msg = require('./msg.js')(io);
```

msg.js

```
// define module constructor that accepts the io variable
var io;
module.exports = function(importIO) {
    io = importIO;
}

// elsewhere in the module
io.emit(...)
```

Comment: Thank you now I guess I got how it should be done. Although i made a way around that and decided to just create global events and listen to these global events in app.js file where my socket.io was working then emitting socket.io itself. Next time I will use your method.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
```

And it's working now (not pulling an error) but still not sending it to the client.

Comment: This likely isn't working because you've created a new `io` object that is not hooked to your web server and thus not connected to the current webSocket connections.